# ROC curve frequencies deviate

Tags: classification, frequency, roc

I've got a question of understanding on ROC curve.

For estimation of an optimal cut point for a biomarker, I selected an anchor and performed a ROC analysis. The anchor event is quite rare (about 5%).
The event when classifying now with the novel optimal cut point is much more frequent (about 20%). This of course results in a low PPV and high NPV.

Can anyone help me understand this deviation in frequencies. I cannot really wrap my head around it.

Thanks a lot!

search already for some answers, but couldn't really find anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it's not really about the code, but a matter of understanding I'd say